# Is there any way to instruct php CLI NOT to load certain modules without specifying a separate ini file?

Tags: php, module, command-line-interface

Long story short:

We use php for a large number of CLI scripts.

When we do a pmap dump of a cli process, we noticed that php CLI is loading certain "used in web mode only" exntesions.

For example:

```
[root@XXXX php.d]# pmap 5956 | grep apc
00007fe5d0356000    132K r-x--  /usr/lib/XXXX/apc.so
00007fe5d0377000   2048K -----  /usr/lib/XXXX/apc.so
00007fe5d0577000     12K rw---  /usr/lib/XXXX/apc.so
[root@XXXX php.d]#
```

As you can see, pid 5956 is loading apc.so even tho its a CLI based php process.

This is a waste of memory since APC is never used on the CLI end (unless specifically instructed to do so, doesnt apply to us).

There are a few other extensions we only use for "web mode".

Before we go ahead and create, and thus have to maintain 2 seperate php.ini files, we were wondering:

Is there a way to instruct php / php.ini to load certain modules ONLY on non-CLI mode?

Thanks.

---

**Dump for comments below:**

```
[root@XXXX mod_geoip_1.3.5]# pmap 13330 -x | grep apc ; pmap 18151 -x | grep apc
00007f1a883c9000     132      56       0 r-x--  apc.so
00007f1a883ea000    2048       0       0 -----  apc.so
00007f1a885ea000      12      12      12 rw---  apc.so
00007f7404573000     132      56       0 r-x--  apc.so
00007f7404594000    2048       0       0 -----  apc.so
00007f7404794000      12      12      12 rw---  apc.so
[root@XXXX mod_geoip_1.3.5]# man pmap
```

Dump for 2 processes, both cron jobs and thus cli based php processes.

If the memory address is different, I am assuming the space used by them is not shared?

Comment: Keep in mind that most of that memory is shared. Only the third (12K) segment in your listing is private.

Comment: I have to admit, I am not so fluent with linux memory handling internals, so bare with me. But even with a process that is started individually the libraries/etc loaded are in shared memory? Eg: If I execute php .... in one console, and php .... in another console, when possible, the libraries/etc they load will reside in shared memory and thus be loaded only once? Sorry for my poor terminology here, I dont know how to better word this ;)

Comment: Yes -- read-only segments of shared libraries are mmapped into the process, and are thus shared between all processes which use them. The load address does not need to be the same for this to work.

Comment: Added details in question above, but the memory address used by apc.so is different for 2 individually running php cli processes. Im assuming they are not 'sharing' the same memory space?

Comment: Thank you kindly for the FYI. I did not previously know this.

Answer (score 0):

*runs `man php`*

*reads*

Create `php-cli.ini` which excludes the ones you don't want.